# why is it necessary to implement a provider that throws exception when you manually seed a value?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

While using google guice I came across this documentation of how to manually seed values in request scope.

[https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule#dispatch-order]

You can implement a custom filter to seed values to be injected later e.g.

```
   protected Filter createUserIdScopingFilter() {
     return new Filter() {
       @Override public void doFilter(
          ServletRequest request,  ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
         HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
         // ...you'd probably want more sanity checking here
         Integer userId = Integer.valueOf(httpRequest.getParameter("user-id"));
         httpRequest.setAttribute(
             Key.get(Integer.class, Names.named("user-id")).toString(),
             userId);  
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }

      @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

      @Override public void destroy() { }
     };
  }
```

In this documentation they are explaining the binding as

And the binding might look like this:

```
  public class YourServletModule extends ServletModule {
     @Override protected void configureServlets() {
         .....
        filter("/process-user*").through(createUserIdScopingFilter());
    }

    @Provides @Named("user-id") @RequestScoped Integer provideUserId() {
      throw new IllegalStateException("user id must be manually seeded");
    }
  }
```

I would like to understand why is it necessary to implement a provides method that throws an exception ? What is its purpose ?

Comment: I usually use this system for none abstract class to be usable but throw an exception for some method that should not be used directly, but override in a sub class (only in existing project, there are cleaner ways to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes in Guice are implemented by taking a `Provider` and wrapping it in a new `Provider`: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/Scope.html#scope-com.google.inject.Key-com.google.inject.Provider-

There must be some initial provider to wrap, even if that one doesn't do anything useful.

In fact, if you omit the provider from the module, Guice will find dependencies on `@Named("user-id") Integer`, but no provider for it, and fail to even create the injector.  It needs to be able to wire up every dependency to a provider ahead of time.